# Stream Audio to Bluetooth Device in C#

Tags: bluetooth, audio-streaming, 32feet

I am trying to stream Audio to a bluetooth device in-code in C#. I've picked up the 32feet.net library to help with this. I am able to get a bluetooth speaker paired just fine, and then I use the code below to connect to the device.

```
    globalClient.BeginConnect(device.DeviceAddress, BluetoothService.SerialPort, new AsyncCallback(BluetoothConnectedAsyncHandler), device);
```

Async Callback method:

```
    private void BluetoothConnectedAsyncHandler(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        BluetoothDeviceInfo connectedDevice = (BluetoothDeviceInfo)result.AsyncState;

        globalClient.EndConnect(result);

        if (result.IsCompleted)
        {
            NetworkStream btStream = globalClient.GetStream();
        }
    }
```

This all works well, but when I try to set the service from BluetoothService.SerialPort to BluetoothService.AudioSource, then I receive a SocketException on the "globalClient.EndConnect(result);" line saying "A socket operation failed because the destination host was down". See screenshot:

[image: Socket Exception]

I've also tried to throw data at the speaker through the NetworkStream when it is setup with BluetoothService.SerialPort, but it doesn't play anything - no noise or static.

My running hypothesis is that this can't be done easily with 32feet.net, and I would have to code up the a2dp spec in code. I think the 32feet.net library is used so that I can tell the Operating System to use the speaker as an output device, rather than control audio output in-code as a supported feature.

Please help! Has anyone done this?

Would it even work if I sent an a2dp compliant stream to the device over the BluetoothService.SerialPort connection?

A2DP spec: https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/DownloadDoc.ashx?doc_id=8236

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Were you able to find a way to send audio over Bluetooth to a speaker?

Comment: No, see the update below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

This isn't possible within the 32feet.net library, you can only set the device up to talk the the Microsoft audio service using the setService method call in 32feet.net

www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/32feet.NET/InTheHand.Net.Personal/MicrosoftSdpService/M/SetService

This MS service manages the A2DP output to the device. There is no way to directly output audio from code into the Bluetooth Device using this library in C#.

Comment: is it still the case

Comment: I would assume so, but this investigation is 5 years old now, and Microsoft is converting a ton of Windows 10 functionality (Control Panel, etc.) to use C# based view layouts and rendering - so it is possible that there are some new libraries or APIs available. Let us know what you find!